# Multivariate normal joint density of two correlated ($\rho$ = 1) variables

Tags: distributions, correlation, normal-distribution, density-function, independence

I cannot find a close form solution to calculate the normal joint probability of two variables assuming they are fully correlated ($\rho$=1).

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What non-closed-form solutions have you found?  And since two perfectly correlated variables are almost surely equal, you're really asking for the probability function of a *single* Normal variable--so what is the obstacle to finding that?  Is it that you are concerned about mathematically describing a singular multivariate distribution (which indeed can be complicated)?  If so, please see the related post http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/63817 for some ideas.

Comment: This question is nearly identical to [this one](http://stats.stackexchange.com/q/230860/127790) which I had attempted (badly) to answer, as well as a few other ones. All of these either have no accepted answer, or the question is not quite the same. It might be worthwhile to get an authoritative answer here, for future reference. (A hint of one for the more general case is currently at [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multivariate_normal_distribution#Degenerate_case).)

Comment: Joint density does not exist when $\rho=1$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately when two variables are fully correlated i.e $\rho=1$  the covariance matrix ${\displaystyle {\boldsymbol {\Sigma }}}$ is not invertible . This is a  Degenerate case.

The formula for normal joint probability is given by:

\begin{align}
f_{\mathbf x}(x_1,\ldots,x_k) =
\frac{1}{\sqrt{(2\pi)^{k}|\boldsymbol\Sigma|}}
\exp\left(-\frac{1}{2}({\mathbf x}-{\boldsymbol\mu})^\mathrm{T}{\boldsymbol\Sigma}^{-1}({\mathbf x}-{\boldsymbol\mu})
\right).
\end{align}

The covariance matrix for the two variable case is given by:
 $$\Sigma = \begin{pmatrix} \sigma_X^2 & \rho \sigma_X \sigma_Y \\
                             \rho \sigma_X \sigma_Y  & \sigma_Y^2\end{pmatrix}.$$

Setting $\rho=1$ we get:

$$\Sigma = \begin{pmatrix} \sigma_X^2 & \sigma_X \sigma_Y \\
                             \sigma_X \sigma_Y  & \sigma_Y^2\end{pmatrix},$$

the determinant of this  matrix is zero:
$$det(\Sigma)=\sigma_X^2\sigma_Y^2-\sigma_X \sigma_Y\sigma_X \sigma_Y=0,$$

therefor not invertible

You can also see this with the formula for normal joint probability of two variables $x$ and $y$ is given by:

\begin{align}
 f(x,y)=
      \frac{1}{2 \pi  \sigma_X \sigma_Y \sqrt{1-\rho^2}}
      \exp\left(
        -\frac{1}{2(1-\rho^2)}\left[
          \frac{(x-\mu_X)^2}{\sigma_X^2} +
          \frac{(y-\mu_Y)^2}{\sigma_Y^2} -
          \frac{2\rho(x-\mu_X)(y-\mu_Y)}{\sigma_X \sigma_Y}
        \right]
      \right)\\
\end{align}

if $\rho=1$ we get division by zero.

Comment: Although this explains the *problem*, how does it provide an *answer*?